# How can I set custom /location to /location/index.html

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I was trying to deploy a Gitbook page on a nginx server, and I have a location like this `http://localhost/introduction/`, but it seems it can't get index.html in the folder 'root/_book/introduction', so it can't display normally. but if I visit `http://localhost/introduction/index.html`, it can display normally.

I've tried to set `location ~ ^((?!\.html$).)*$` to match the pathname which not end with .html, but I don't know how to deal with the configs.

```
location / {
    #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    root   /root/_book;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

And my path tree

```
./_book
├── index.html
├── introduction
│   ├── authorization.html
│   ├── configuration.html
│   ├── index.html
│   └── install.html
```

only when I visit `http://localhost/introduction/` it can't display normally.

I want config a commonly rule that can automatically redirect the `/pathname` to `/pathname/index.html` or render `/pathname/index.html` when I visit '/pathname'.

Comment: Did you check logs? Could you post the full `nginx.conf`? /Offtopic: is it good idea to use root's directory?/

Comment: You need to use `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`